# Bootstrap How to open multiple modal at the same time each one below another?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I wanted to put the charts (chartjs) on modal but it looks very messy putting 3 charts in one modal. So my client decided to have those 3 charts each inside a separate modal and wanted it to be opened at the same time and that each modal is below one another.

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-white" onclick="loadChart()" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#chartModal">
<i class="fe fe-sliders me-1"></i> 
More
</button>

<!-- Charts Modal -->
<!-- Sign-ups -->
<div id="chartModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xxl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Sign up Chart</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="chart">
                                <canvas id="signUpsChartModal" class="chart-canvas"></canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Charts Modal -->
<!-- New Sign-ups -->
<div id="chartModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xxl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">New Sign up Chart</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="row align-items-end">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h4 class="header-title text-white">New Sign ups</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chart">
                            <canvas id="newSignUpsChartModal" class="chart-canvas"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Charts Modal -->
<!-- Hits -->
<div id="chartModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xxl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Hits Chart</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">

                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="row align-items-end">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h4 class="header-title text-white">Hits</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chart">
                            <canvas id="hitsChartModal" class="chart-canvas"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my current code. How can I achieve the modal stacked one another and then opened at the same time? Knowing that "*Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time*" from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#how-it-works)

This should be 3 and scrollable (I can only fit 2 for screenshot[image])